# Error ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined (Chrome Console Error - not during gulp / babel build)

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, gulp, babeljs

I have a bit of a strange issue that I'm hoping I can get some help with.

I've got a WordPress theme that I've been developing using a dev setup including gulp & babel. I have a hosting provider with a development environment, and production environment. Up until now, I have had no issues building the theme, uploading it to the dev environment and testing it - it's all been pretty smooth.

Now I'm trying to upload the same theme (I'm talking exactly the same), to the production site, instead of the development site, and I get the following error in the console:

```
Error retrieving XXX:  ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at bundle.js?ver=1.0.0:726
    at S (bundle.js?ver=1.0.0:726)
    at window.initMap (bundle.js?ver=1.0.0:726)
    .....
```

Everything that I've searched for has indicated that people have been getting this issue when trying to build or run their development environments, and it has something to do with their gulp or babel setup, or the packages they're using. So, I'll add my config below... Although I'm stumped as to why the theme builds and runs in one environment error-free, and falls over with this error in another.

gulpfile.babel.js

```
// Gulp.js configuration
'use strict';

import "regenerator-runtime/runtime.js";
import "core-js/stable";

const

  // Gulp and plugins
  { src,
    dest, 
    watch, 
    series, 
    parallel 
  }             = require('gulp'),
  imagemin      = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  autoprefixer  = require('autoprefixer'),
  cssnano       = require('cssnano'),
  sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
  sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
  postcss       = require('gulp-postcss'),
  gulpif        = require('gulp-if'),
  cleanCss      = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  yargs         = require('yargs'),
  del           = require('del'),
  webpack       = require('webpack-stream')
 
[...]

// Task to build js file as bundle.js
export const scripts = () => {
  return src([
    js.src + 'map.js',
    js.src + 'bundle.js'
  ])
  .pipe(webpack({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization:{
      namedChunks: true,
      minimize: true, 
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendors',
            chunks: 'async'
          },
        }
      }
    },
    mode: PRODUCTION ? 'production' : 'development',
    devtool: !PRODUCTION ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
    output: {
      filename: js.filename
    },
  }))
  .pipe(dest(js.build))
}

[...]
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead",
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "corejs": 3
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

I tried updating the package.json to use @babel/runtime as a dependancy, along with regenerator-runtime, which I didn't think would do anything - and it didn't.

package.json

```
"browserslist": [
        "last 3 and_chr versions",
        "last 3 chrome versions",
        "last 3 opera versions",
        "last 3 ios_saf versions",
        "last 3 safari versions"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/register": "^7.10.5",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.8.5",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
        "del": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
        "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
        "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
        "scss": "^0.2.4",
        "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
        "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1",
        "yargs": "^15.4.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.5",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
        "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.1"
    }
```

The particular piece of code which is throwing the error is in my map.js (pulls custom posts from the wp-rest api, and populates them on the google map), and is below:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'; // top of file

[...]

const getXXX = () => {
    try{
      async function fetchXXX() {
        const res = await fetch(url);

        if(!res.ok){
          console.log('Error retrieving XXX:', res.status);
          throw new Error(res.status);
        }
        const data = await res.json();
        return data;
      }

      fetchXXX()
      .then(data => {
        xxx = data;
        renderXXX();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error retriving XXX: ', error);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error retrieving XXX: ', err);
    } 
  }
```

If anyone has any pointers, it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this issue in the future (probably unlikely).

It turns out the culprit was the CDN being used in our production environment. I figured out that the bundle.js file I was uploading wasn't the same as was being served up in the site, and turned the CDN off which seemed to fix the issue. :/